# Dealing with binary streams read from the web

Tags: html, binary, raku

I use wget to read a page from the web. But sometimes I get gzipped binary stream instead of plain text html file. What is the best way to decide if the data I get is binary or plain text? If I try to match the data with letter or number (text), I simply get "Malformed UTF-8".

```
my $result = run << wget -k -q -O $aPage "$aURL" >>, :err;
```

I need to know if $result is binary (gzip) or plain text.

```
if $result ~~ / <:L + :N> / { } # this will fail with "Malformed UTF-8" if $result is a binary stream
```

Is there a Raku package to get a plain text html page source from ANY url?

Comment: Sorry, the data received from the web should be in the file $aPage, not in $result. I later slurp() the file $aPage, and I try to find out if it is binary or text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the best way to decide if the data I get is binary or plain text?

Perhaps the most general answer is perhaps to turn to the Raku module [Data::TextOrBinary](https://raku.land/github:jnthn/Data::TextOrBinary), which can be used to determine if some data is likely to be text or binary; it's a heuristic approach.

The best way to determine the nature of a HTTP response is to look at the `Content-type` header. Rather than calling out to `wget`, try one of the various Raku HTTP modules, which can be installed with the `zef` package manager. For example, you can use [`Cro::HTTP::Client`](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-client):

```
use Cro::HTTP::Client;
my $response = await $aURL;
say "Content is " ~ $response.content-type;
my $body = await $response.body;
say $body ~~ Blob ?? "It's binary!" !! "It's not binary!";
```

> If I try to match the data with letter or number (text), I simply get "Malformed UTF-8".

By default `run` assumes that is what it will get. You can also pass the `:bin` argument to `run`, in order to get a `Blob` (any binary data) rather than having it to to decode it automatically. However, you'll still need to decide what to do in the event it's not textual data.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan Worthington ! I will install the Data::TextOrBinary module and the Cro::HTTP::Client module, and I will try out other http modules. Thanks.